# What is wrong in this solution to a codejam quiz?

Tags: c++

Link of the question https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4224486/dashboard

My solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int type_A(vector<int>vec){    // function for method 1 of computation;
int ret = 0;
for(auto i = 0;i<vec.size()-1;i++){
  int a = vec[i],b=vec[i+1];
  if(a>b)ret = ret+(a-b);
}
return ret;
}  // end of 1st function

int type_B(vector<int>vec){ // function for method 2 of computation
    int ret = 0;
    for(auto i = 0;i<vec.size()-1;i++){
        if(i==vec.size()-2){
            if(vec[i]>vec[i+1])ret+=(vec[i]-vec[i+1]);
        }else{
         ret += vec[i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
// end of function
    int main()
    {
      ifstream input("input_file.in");
      ofstream output("output_file.out");
      int t;
      input>>t;
      for(auto i =1;i<=t;i++){
            int n;
      input>>n;
       vector<int>vec(n);
    for(auto j = 0;j<vec.size();j++){
        int x;
        input >>x;
        vec[j] =x;
    }
       output << "Case #" << i << ": " <<  type_A(vec) << " " << type_B(vec) << endl;


      }

    }
```

When I run some examples given with the problems , I get the correct output but when I upload my output file to codejam it says that the answer is incorrect . Please help .

Comment: Your method 2 fails to take into account the fixed minimal "eating speed" - you'll need to determine that first. I believe this is a failing testcase: "10 5 0" (the answer should be 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong for type 2. It just happens that all of the examples happen to have the greatest difference items being between the second last item and the last item, which your code relies on (the test for `i==vec.size()-2`). This is obviously not the case for all of the full tests.

You will need to think of a different algorithm.